# Error getting device handle

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, guid

I have been trying to interface to a device driver for a GPS interface card.  The examples that I have from the vendor are in C++.  I am trying to get it working in C# using pinvoke

```
class HaveQuick
{
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(
        ref Guid ClassGuid,
        IntPtr Enumerator,
        IntPtr hwndParent,
        uint Flags
        );

    [DllImport(@"setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(
       IntPtr hDevInfo,
       ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfo,
       ref Guid interfaceClassGuid,
       UInt32 memberIndex,
       ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData
    );

        Guid GUID_DEVINTERFACE_IPHQT = new Guid(0x13ff045f, 0xe9d2, 0x479c, 0xb3, 0x90, 0x8c, 0xae, 0xc7, 0xd1, 0x1c, 0xc4);
        hDeviceInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref GUID_DEVINTERFACE_IPHQT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
        if (hDeviceInfo == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Console.WriteLine("**Error: couldn't get class info error code = {0}\n");
            return;
        }

             // Find the interface for device
        devNum = 0x0000;    
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA interfaceData = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();                // Interface data for this device
        interfaceData.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(interfaceData);
        SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
        deviceInfoData.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(deviceInfoData);
        success = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDeviceInfo, ref deviceInfoData, ref GUID_DEVINTERFACE_IPHQT, devNum, ref interfaceData);
        if (!success)
        {
            lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Console.WriteLine("**Error: couldn't enum device error number = {0}\n", lastError);
```

}

When I run the code I get lasterror = 87 which is Invalid Parameter

If I replace with this line of code
            success = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDeviceInfo, IntPtr.Zero, ref GUID_DEVINTERFACE_IPHQT, devNum, ref interfaceData);

I get lasterror = 1784 Invlid user buffer.

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you want help with the Invalid user buffer error, you probably should post a new question. Include the C++ prototypes for the functions, and the C++ and C# versions of the structures you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SetupDiGetClassDevs` prototype doesn't have `SetLastError=true`. So the call to `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` might not be getting the correct value. Also, you shouldn't check the last error unless the value returned from the call is invalid.

As the documentation for [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360.aspx) says:

> You should call the GetLastError function immediately when a
>   function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful
>   data.

So the pattern to use `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` should be:

```
IntPtr hDeviceInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs( ... );
if (hDeviceInfo == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    // error here
    lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
}
```

If you check the last error when there was no error, there's no telling what value you'll get. Not all functions call `SetLastError` with a value of 0 when they succeed. So you might be getting an error from long ago.

Comment: Thanks @Jim Mischel  That was it.  So my problem is then when I get the Device interface

Comment: By the way, `IntPtr.Zero` might not be the value to check for. Some functions use `-1` as the invalid handle value (because 0 can be a valid handle in some cases).